# Debian looks strange using XFCE 4.10

Tags: debian, xfce4

I upgraded xfce from 4.8 to 4.10 and got the look you can see in the picture.

Don't know what's the deal. I've been googling but haven't found the solution but seen that people encountered the problem.

Does anyone have any thought?

[image]

Comment: The answer is somewhere in the changelogs, but I don't have the time to parse it http://xfce.org/download/changelogs/4.10

Comment: @Braiam Unfortunately, I haven't found the solution :-(